# How do I put in an integer in triple quote input?

Tags: python

The code goes as follows:

```
minmotocena = 500
maxmotocena = 80000
minmototax = 50
maxmototax = 400

# define ievada funkciju
def intro():
    ikat = int(input("""

Izvēlies kategoriju:
1 - Lietotie auto (""", minlautocena,""" - """, maxlautocena,""")
2 - Mazlietotie auto (""", minmautocena,""" - """, maxmautocena,""")
3 - Salons (""", minsautocena,""" - """, maxsautocena,""")
4 - Custom Superņiki (""", mincautocena,""" - """, maxcautocena,""")
5 - Motocikli (""", minmotocena,""" - """, maxmotocena,""")

Izvēle: """))
```

How do I put those int values in the middle of the quote?

Comment: In recent Pythons version you can use f-strings, with syntax like `{minlautocena}` directly in the string.

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

From Python 3.6 on you can use f-strings like this:

```
def intro():
    ikat = int(input(f"""

Izvēlies kategoriju:
1 - Lietotie auto ({minlautocena} - {maxlautocena})
2 - Mazlietotie auto ({minmautocena} - {maxmautocena})
3 - Salons ({minsautocena} - {maxsautocena})
4 - Custom Superņiki ({mincautocena} - {maxcautocena})
5 - Motocikli ({minmotocena} - {maxmotocena})

Izvēle: """))
```

In earlier version you can use `.format()`, the old style `%` formatting, or (the less beautiful) string concatenation with `+`.

Comment: And what does the f right after input and before quotes mean?

Comment: That is what actually makes it an f-string and allows the `{ }` syntax inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) only takes one parameter, which is the prompt. That means, you can't use `,` as a separator like `print()` does.

Therefore, replace

```
""", minlautocena,"""
```

by

```
""" + str(minlautocena) + """
```

or use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)